# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to hit a laravel api  and display it in flutter.

```
[
    {
        "doctor_name": "abhishek",
        "username": "abhishek",
        "uid": "aLSb7ebMfsfAxybrwq21kXjkcJM2",
        "fees": 500,
        "speciality": "Oncologist"
    },
    {
        "username": "amanboi",
        "uid": "wpTQALmZd5Yr5BVQyblNstjet1A3",
        "fees": 500,
        "speciality": "Oncologist",
        "doctor_name": "aman"
    }
]
```

I get the error when i try to map it to my model. This is what my model look like

```
class Doctor {
  final String uid;
  final int fee;
  final String doctor_name;
  final String speciality;

  Doctor({this.uid, this.fee, this.doctor_name, this.speciality});

  factory Doctor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Doctor(
      uid: json['userId'],
      fee: json['fee'],
      doctor_name: json['doctor_name'],
      speciality: json['speciality']
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my function

```
Future<Doctor> doctorlist(String speciality ) async {
  final response = await http.post('http://192.168.0.101:8080/querysnapshot', body: {'speciality': speciality});
  print('got response successfully');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    return Doctor.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

error i  get :

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `List` you got from your API into the model.
Return the List.

```dart
Future<List> doctorlist(String speciality) async {
  final response = await http.post('http://192.168.0.101:8080/querysnapshot', body: {'speciality': speciality});
  print('got response successfully');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

In your ListView you can do something like this

```dart
ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Doctor doctor = Doctor.fromJson(doctorList[index]);
        return Text(doctor.name);
      },
    );
```

Comment: but one thing if i put 0 it would just return the first index to that json map what do i do to send rest

Comment: [
    {
        "doctor_name": "abhishek",
        "username": "abhishek",
        "uid": "aLSb7ebMfsfAxybrwq21kXjkcJM2",
        "fees": 500,
        "speciality": "Oncologist"
    },
    {
        "username": "amanboi",
        "uid": "wpTQALmZd5Yr5BVQyblNstjet1A3",
        "fees": 500,
        "speciality": "Oncologist",
        "doctor_name": "aman"
    }
]

Comment: What do you want to do with the `List`?

Comment: i want to create the list of all the doctors name in that response

Comment: The you need to return the list not a Doctor model.

Comment: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<Doctor>'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'Doctor' is from 'package:demoflutter/repository/models_class.dart' ('lib/repository/models_class.dart').
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
        Doctor doctor = Doctor.fromJson(doctorlist[index]);

Comment: You're doing a tonne of things wrongly. You should take sometime to learn about `Future`

Comment: as you said i tried this code but this is the only error it throws `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<Doctor>'`